# How do you call a JSON url data set (using Ajax and jQuery) to create a full page self-updating chart display on a Wordpress page?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, wordpress, url

I downloaded all the supportive plugins and Wordpress does not display the data. Here is the code that I am using to embed the data to a page:

`<script> <div class="result"></div>
     <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function() {
        jQuery.ajax( {
           url: "http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/markets.json",
        }). done(
        function( data ) {
           var data = JSON.parse(data);
    </script>`

Can somebody please provide me with some guidance on displaying json url data to create a markets update chart for a wordpress page? Thanks in advance!

Here is the data url API: http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/markets.json

Answer (score 0):

You need to study some basics, because both markup and JavaScript syntax are completely messed up.

However, you could organize the code like this:

```
<div class="result"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/markets.json",
    type: "json"
  }).done(function( data ) {
    var data = JSON.parse(data);
    // put the code to populate #result element
  });
}
</script>
```

If you want the function to repeat you'll need to put a setInterval that will periodically re-execute the code.

Comment: Yeah I'm a noob with jQuery and Ajax. First time attempting to program a json url call; thank you very much for the insight.

Comment: No problem! Once you've opened a <script> tag you can't no longer put HTML code until the closing tag, but you have to put the script language (JavaScript in this case). Just a starting point :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
<div class="result"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/markets.json",
    type: "json"
  }).done(function( data ) {
    var data = JSON.parse(data);
    success: function( json ) {
           $.each(json, function(i, optionHtml){
              $('data').append(optionHtml);
         });
  });
}

function repeatMe(){
 $.ajax({
  url: 'url',
  dataType: 'json',
  cache: true,
  timeout: 30000,
  success: function(data) {
        $('#output ul').empty();
        $.each(data.posts, function(i,data){ 

            $('#output ul').append('<li><a href="'+data.image+'"><img class="thumb" src="'+data.image+'" alt="" /></a><h3>'+data.title+'</h3><p>'+data.text+'</p></li>');
            setTimeout(repeatMe, 5000);
        });
    },
    error: function(){
        $('#output ul').append('<li>Error');
        setTimeout(repeatMe, 5000);
    }
 });
}
</script>
```